# Google+ integration, authentication and sharing

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-plus

In my application I have integrate the Google+ and all things (i.e. authentication, sharing etc...) working fine with application, but the problem is that when I tap on google plus SignIn button it goes to Safari for authentication and after SingIn it go back to application.

Again it same for the Sharing (it just navigate to Safari browser and after sharing content it go back to application). This scenario work perfectly.

I have downloaded code from the bellow link.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

But, now I want scenario in which, user should be able to login and share on Google+ like facebook and Twitter working.

And my new scenario is feasible because it's working fine Flipboard iphone/iPad application.

I want like that.

I have spent much to search on it but still I didn't got the answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipboard has a partnership with Google+ : http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57455826-93/flipboard-becomes-prominent-google-partner/ so you can't replicate their functionality at the moment.